# Htaccess - the request handler for subdomains

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Need to make a generic handler that will check for the presence of a folder in a specific directory.
Below is my htaccess file with comments.

```
Options -Indexes 
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#
# redirect www requests
#
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
#
# processing the request
#
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?(.*)\.(.*)\.(.*)$
#
# without this line there is an error 500, in the logs there is a loop error
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !subdomains/
#
# if folder exists refers to subdomain 
#
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subdomains/%2 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdomains/%2/$1 [L,QSA]
#
# if not, and the request does not point to an existing file, then we pass the necessary parameters to the index.php
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?sd=%2&route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

*www.any.example.com -> any.example.com* - OK

*existing.example.com -> existing.example.com* - OK

**example.com/subdomains/any*/ *-> example.com (index.php?sd=&route=subdomains/any/)** - OK

Here are the problems that I can not solve

<s>*nonexistent.example.com -> example.com (index.php?sd=nonexistent)* - NO DATA IN "sd"</s>

> It was decided not to transfer the subdomain variable and parse it
>   directly via HTTP_HOST in the script itself.

*example.com/existingfolder-> example.com (index.php?sd=&route=existingfolder)* - REDIRECT TO "example.com/existingfolder/?sd=&route=existingfolder"

Who knows how to fix it?

Comment: A RewriteCond only affects the next following RewriteRule. Your last rule is preceeded by only one condition, and that condition does not do any grouping, so there simply is no `%2` to access in the substitution part of the rule.

Comment: Then if I add `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?(.*)\.(.*)\.(.*)$` again before the second rule, when I go to _example.com/nonexistentfolder_, the page **Not Found**  opens instead of index.php

Comment: It was decided not to transfer the subdomain variable and parse it directly via HTTP_HOST in the script itself. However, the problem with redirects in the absence of a slash on the end was not solved

Comment: Found a way out of the situation using `DirectorySlash Off`, if someone finds a more competent approach would be very grateful